# python and gdal for image processing

Tags: python, gdal

i have a database catalogue that reads images path as well as other attributes and there is a part that tries to open the dataset in the code so that other processe can go on if the opening was sucessfull but i have hit a stumblimg block as to how to tell the process to go on after the following code, the code runs smoothly but when it encounters an image it can not open it stops instead of going to the begining to read the database again and open a new image.

```
try:  
    hDataset = gdal.Open( pszFilename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )  
    except IOError:  
    print("gdalinfo failed - unable to open '%s'." % pszFilename )  
    status = "UPDATE %s SET job = 11  WHERE id = %s" % (table,row[2])  
    setstatus = conn.cursor()  
    setstatus.execute(status)  
    conn.commit()  
    setstatus.close()  
else:  
    print "file opened sucessfully"  
    hDataset.close()
```

Comment: Try to determine which line is causing the hangup (a few diagnostic print statements would probably tell you).  Note that not all `gdal.Open` failures will generate an `IOError` exception (for example, if the file doesn't exist, no exception will be thrown) so you might want to capture general exceptions as well.

Answer (score 0):

GDAL does not normally throw exceptions, which is a shame. With `gdal.UseExceptions()` turned on, it sometimes throws `RuntimeError` (only!), but I haven't found this feature very reliable.

Some functions with GDAL return `None` if unsuccessful, and others return a status integer, where 0 is good and non-zero is an error code.

A typical form I use is something like this:

```
hDataset = gdal.Open(pszFilename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
if hDataset is None:
    raise IOError("Could not open '%s'" % (pszFilename,))

band_num = 1
band = hDataset.GetRasterBand(band_num)
if band is None:
    raise AttributeError("Raster band %s cannot be fetched" % (band_num,))
...
```